# yii2 How can I get the textInput value and send to another textInput

Tags: php, yii2, textinput

I am new for Yii2 and I have a question.

In my _form.php (generated automatically by gii) I have two fields (textInput)

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Test1')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'Test2')->textInput() ?>
```

I want to get Test1's (textInput) value and get Test2's value, and send the total value to another textInput.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Test3')->textInput() ?>
```

I want to see the total value in the Test3 (textInput).

Can anyone help me please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adding custom javascript in your view

```
<?php
$this->registerJs('

    jQuery(document).on("change" ,"#'. Html::getInputId($model ,'Test2') .'" ,function(){
        $("#'. Html::getInputId($model ,'Test3') .'").val();
        var first = $("#'. Html::getInputId($model ,'Test1') .'").val();
        var second = $("#'. Html::getInputId($model ,'Test2') .'").val();
        var third = first +"  " + second;
        $("#'. Html::getInputId($model ,'Test3') .'").val(third);

    });

');

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwer but I want to explain something more for ex. I have 100 in textInput1 and 200 in textInput2. Then I want to 100 + 200 = 300 in my textInput 3. How can I edit ypur function

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `Test3` to your model as property.
2. Create getter

`public function getTest3()
 {
     return $this->Test1 . " " . $this->Test2;
 }`